# extra qualification error in DevC++ IDE with TDM-GCC 4.9.2

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have a class function that is defined as follows:

```
class Output 
{ 

private:

window* pWind;  

public:

Output();

    window* CreateWind(int, int, int, int);
    void CreateDesignToolBar(); //Tool bar of the design mode
    void CreateSimulationToolBar();//Tool bar of the simulation mode
    window * getwindow()const;
    void CreateStatusBar();
    void CreateDrawArea();

    Input* CreateInput(); //creates a pointer to the Input object   
    void ClearStatusBar();  //Clears the status bar
    void ClearDrawArea();   //Clears the drawing area

    void DrawAssign(Point Left, int width, int height, string Text, bool Selected = false);
   void Output::Drawcondition(Point left, int width, int height, int t_width, int t_height, string Text, bool Selected = false);
```

When I compile the source in DevC++, I get:

33  7   C:\Users\user\source\repos\flowchart-designer-and-simulator\GUI\Output.h    [Error] extra qualification 'Output::' on member 'Drawcondition' [-fpermissive]

What is this? How do I remove this error?

Comment: remove `Output::` from line 33

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Dev-C++ is not a compiler, but an IDE (a fancy editor, simply said). It uses some kind of other compiler under the bonnet. Proabably gcc (from MINGW), I don't really remember, as Dev-C++ is quite dated tool.

Secondly, you have not given full code (EDIT: full code was added later), but based on the error I think you have declared a method inside of class and qualified it with that class name. This is incorrect, as qualification there is not needed.

I.e. you should do something like this:

```
class Test {
        void test ();
};
```

Not something like this (which, I presume, you have tried):

```
class Test {
        void Test::test ();
};
```